# Configure Eclipse build path and javadoc Google+

Tags: java, eclipse, google-api, google-plus

What's the right way to configure an Eclipse Java project (NOT Android!!! it's going to be a CLI application), based on [Java Quick Start app](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java), to add the libraries and documentation to its build path?

First of all, I created a new project. Then, I moved the source from the original directory (from Google) to my project's src. After this, I copied the "lib" directory to the root of my project and refreshed.

I did "configure build path" but:
1) adding `lib` as "Class folder" doesn't take the import errors out
2) adding all the files (via Cmd-A on "Add External JARs...") makes the project runnable but the documentation isn't loaded (mouse-over method does not show the javadoc for it).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you stick with `Add External JARs` (If you don't the below process is very much the same)

- On the project, select `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` and choose the `Libraries` tab.
- Select one of the external JARs you added and expand it. You will see `Source attachment`, `Javadoc location`, and more
- Set the `Javadoc location` to the appropriate location. Or, if you have the source jar (which presumably include the Javadoc) you could set that.

The Javadoc will now be available.